# How do I get the number of members in a structure?

Tags: c, runtime, structure

I want to count the number of members in a structure.
For example:

```
typedef struct
{
    char    MrChar;
    int MrInt;
    long    MrLong;
} Bg_Typedef;
Bg_Typedef FooStr;
```

I create a function prototype that should return number of members in the structure

```
int NumberOfMem(Bg_Typedef *psStructure);
```

=> NumberOfMem(&FooStr) should return 3

Comment: I don't think you can do that. BTW, what is your algorithm to achieve this?

Comment: @Rohan: That is precisely the Q OP asks (*How do I get the number of members in a structure?*)

Answer (score 6):

It can be done with [`X_MACRO`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro)'s.

Do something like this:

```
#define X_BG_MEMBERS \
    X(char, MrChar) \
    X(int, MrInt) \
    X(long, MrLong)

typedef struct {
#define X(type, member) type member;
    X_BG_MEMBERS
#undef X
} Bg_Typedef;

Bg_Typedef FooStr;
```

Define a function which will count the members. Can also just be a variable, but make the variable `static const` so that it is not overwritten

```
static int
bg_members_count() {
    #define X(_, __) +1
    static int COUNT = 0
    X_BG_MEMBERS;
    #undef X
    
    return COUNT;
}
```

Now you can do something like this in main:

```
#include <stdio.h>
...

int main() {
    printf("The number of members defined in Bg_Typedef is %d\n", bg_members_count());
}
```

You should get something like:

```
The number of members defined in Bg_Typedef is 3
```

You might also just want a constant, so you can do the following

```
#define X(_, __) +1
static const int COUNT = X_BG_MEMBERS;
#undef X
```

---

### Alternative Pattern

In order to avoid having lots of `#define X...` followed by `#undef X`, it may be beneficial to do something like this instead:

```
#define X_BG_MEMBERS(X) \
    X(char, MrChar) \
    X(int, MrInt) \
    X(long, MrLong)

#define BG_STRUCT_FIELD(type, field) type field;
#define BG_COUNT_MEMBER(_, __) +1

typedef struct {
  X_BG_MEMBERS(BG_STRUCT_FIELD)
} Bg_Typedefarguably;

static int
bg_members_count() {
    static int COUNT = X_BG_MEMBERS(BG_COUNT_MEMBER);    
    return COUNT;
}

// OR constant
// static const int COUNT = X_BG_MEMBERS(BG_COUNT_MEMBER);
```

It works the same as the above, but should be noticeably more readable. See [ref](https://www.embedded.com/reduce-c-language-coding-errors-with-x-macros-part-1/).

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this that is inbuilt into the C language AFAIK. If you want to do this you would need to remember the number of members or hard code the number as return value of your function. C can tell you the size in bytes of your structs but not the number of members they contain. Alternatively you could use a member function of your struct to return the hard coded number of members.

Answer (score 2):

C only allows you to determine the number of bytes a structure requires (including padding bytes) using the `sizeof` operator. As long as the struct members all have the same type, you can use `sizeof(struct foo)/sizeof(membertype)` to compute the number of members. In the general case, with differently sized member types, this is impossible from within the C language (you could post process the source automatically and fill in the result, but that's ugly). C simply does not allow what is called **Introspection** in other languages (like e.g. perl).

But then, you (and the compiler) know the number of members at *compile time*. **Why do you want to compute a known number at runtime**? Maybe you can state the actual problem you are trying to solve and we can point to a solution not involving member counts...

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done in C.

If you really need this, you should try a more high level language which supports reflection. (Java, Python ).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29